# Python and Raspbery Pi: How to perform an action only once in a while loop

Tags: python, email, while-loop, raspberry-pi, gpio

First time being here. I'm not a programmer, and I'm trying to create a simple monitoring system with my RPi, but run into some problems. Hopefully someone can help me on my way?

I have pretty much the exact setup shown here (except the button is a lever/switch): http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch07.html#SEC11.1
and followed some advice on GPIO cleanup here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqk6M_XdIC0

What I need, is when the lever is pressed AND PRESSED DOWN CONSTANTLY, I want to send one e-mail. When the lever is then released, I want the program to "restart" so that when the lever is hold down yet again some time in the future, another mail is sent.

I have gotten the separate imported mail script to work and the hardware setup seems to be working.

What happens is:

1. Start program with `sudo python pellets.py`
2. Press and hold the lever, 1 mail is being sent succesfully, but the program    keeps printing "SENT 1 MAIL" every 3 seconds until I release the lever
   (?).
3. When lever is pressed and hold a second time, no mail is sent (?),
   but the program keeps printing "SENT 1 MAIL" until I release the
   lever.

For the program to send mail again, I need to CTRL+C and break the program and restart the program manually.

What am I missing?

- Why does not the program send a second mail when I release, re-press and hold
  the lever?
- Why does the program keep printing the text message when I keep the
  lever pressed? Shouldn't the loop have ended by now when I set sent_mail=1?

I've tried to clearup the GPIO channel inside the if-loop, but that didn't work as I thought. Then the text continues to print even after I released the lever. However no more mails being sent.

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

mail_sent = 0

try:
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(12)
        if input_state == 0 and mail_sent == 0:
            import pellets_sendmail
            print ('SENT 1 MAIL')
            mail_sent = 1
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            mail_sent = 0
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup(12)
```

Comment: can you show the code in `pellets_sendmail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually two problems.

First, it's printing "SENT 1 MAIL" continuously because the else clause is going to reset your `mail_sent` whether the lever is up *or* `mail_sent` is not 0. You might want to specify that the lever should be up before `mail_sent` can reset:

```
    if input_state == 0 and mail_sent == 0:
        ...
    elif input_state == 1: # Whatever your "up" state is
        mail_sent = 0
```

Second, you can only import another python module once. I assume `pellets_sendmail.py` sends your mail message. The first time it imports it, the file runs as normal, but afterward it does not execute the file again. I recommend making a function inside `pellets_sendmail.py` that sends the message, rather than having your script send the message directly

```
import pellets_sendmail    # put this at the top of your script
...
     if input_state == 0 and mail_sent == 0:
        pellets_sendmail.sendmail()
     ...
```

[Here's a tutorial on writing functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) if you're unsure how to do it. Simply move whatever code you're using to send mail now into its own discrete function (I called it `sendmail()` in my example, but you can call it whatever you want).